# Webpack - how to test production on my machine

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I have 2 webpack config files one for development and one for production.

I would like to test the production config file on my local machine - how do I do that?
In other words I would like to run https://localhost:3000 and see my app while it is in production mode.

The script to run the production config file is `npm run build` which create files in dist directory - how do I serve those files?

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```
// For info about this file refer to webpack and webpack-hot-middleware documentation
    // For info on how we're generating bundles with hashed filenames for cache busting: https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95#.w99i89nsz
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const ExtractTextPlugin  = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    const WebpackChunkHash = require('webpack-chunk-hash');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
    const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
    const path = require('path');
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

    const GLOBALS = {
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
        'process.env.BABEL_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
        'process.env.PORT': 3000,
        __DEV__: false
    };

    module.exports = {
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
        },
        devtool: "eval", // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index'),
        target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: './',
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
        },
        stats: {
            children: false,
        },
        plugins: [
            // Hash the files using MD5 so that their names change when the content changes.
            new WebpackChunkHash({algorithm: 'md5'}), // 'md5' is default value

            // Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),

            // Generate HTML file that contains references to generated bundles. See here for how this works: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#basic-usage
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'public/index.ejs',
                favicon: 'public/styles/images/icon.png',
                minify: {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                    keepClosingSlash: true,
                    minifyJS: true,
                    minifyCSS: true,
                    minifyURLs: true
                },
                inject: true,
                // Note that you can add custom options here if you need to handle other custom logic in index.html
                // To track JavaScript errors via TrackJS, sign up for a free trial at TrackJS.com and enter your token below.
                trackJSToken: ''
            }),

            // Generate an external css file with a hash in the filename
            new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),

            // https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
            new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
                defaultAttribute: 'async'
            }),
            // Minify JS
            new UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: "vendor",
                minChunks: isVendor
            }),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
                    use: ['url-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 10000,
                                mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 10000,
                                mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 10000,
                                mimetype: 'image/svg+xml'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/i,
                    use: ['file-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    minimize: true,
                                    modules: true,
                                    importLoaders: 1,
                                    localIdentName: '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:2]',
                                    sourceMap: true
                                }
                            }, {
                                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                options: {
                                    plugins: () => [
                                        require('autoprefixer')
                                    ],
                                    sourceMap: true
                                }
                            }, {
                                loader: 'sass-loader',
                                options: {
                                    includePaths: [
                                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss'),
                                        path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")
                                    ],
                                    sourceMap: true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                },
            ]
        }
    };

    function isVendor({resource}) {
        return (
            resource && resource.indexOf("node_modules") >= 0 && resource.match(/\.js$/)
        );
    }
```

**server.js**

```
// server.js

// set up ============================================
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config');
const enforce = require("express-sslify");
const compression = require('compression');

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.dbUrl, { useMongoClient: true});

// Init App
const app = express();

// Compress all responses
app.use(compression());

// redirect http requests to https
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));

// Support webpack-dev-server
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    next();
});

// Body Parser Middleware
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// for easier testing with Postman or plain HTML forms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended:true
}));

// Cookie Parser Middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static('public/*.html'));
app.use(express.static('dist'));

// Set Controllers
app.use('/', require('./controllers'));

//------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Set Port
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
});

// Launch
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Meeba started listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `node path/to/server.js` on your config for build.

i.e `webpack -mode production ..etc && node server.js`. Running the server script with node cli. On your server.js script, you already assigned dist folder as static content afterall.

Comment: indeed since I had app.use(express.static('dist')); that should be enough - I had another bug (not related) that masked this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any webserver (e.g. NGINX) to serve your dist folder.
Have a look at [Serving Static Content](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/).

You can get NGINX running with Docker. It can get even easier with [this predefined Docker image](https://github.com/SocialEngine/docker-nginx-spa) to serve SPAs in NGINX.

Comment: Thanks! but I already running a node.js express server - is it really necessary to insert new type of infra? cant I use the existing server.js?

Comment: If you want to have a production like env, I would really recommend NGINX.
But of course NodeJS with Express is also be able to deliver your dist-folder.

Have a look at this example from expressJs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html and https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static

Comment: Well, in production it's a good idea, so might as well do it that way for testing as well.  There are a lot of articles about why,but the upshot is that nginx gives you a lot out of the box that you'd have to add to your express app (and maintain over time) and NGINX will perform better when doing so as well.